# Use inline comments in docker-compose command

Tags: linux, bash, docker, docker-compose, yaml

In my `docker-compose.yml` I need to use a very long `command`, and I want to document it. This is not easily done, but I have a workaround that's ALMOST working.

```
foo:                                    # valid comment
  image: foo:latest                     # valid comment
  command: >
           printf '
           something                    # explanation for this command
           --arg                        # explanation for this switch
           --a                          # explanation
           --b hello
           -c                           # this does...
           --d spam                     # don't use this when...
           #some notes
           --e ham                      # hmmm
           --eggs                       # explanation
           ' |grep -v ^[[:space:]]*$ |grep -v ^# |cut -d# -f1   # valid comment
  restart: always                       # valid comment
```

So every command and switch can be commented.

The bash:

- `printf ' ... '` prints all the stuff as text, to be run as a command
- `grep -v ^[[:space:]]*$` ignores the first empty line
- `grep -v ^#` ignores comment lines
- `cut -d# -f1` strips inline comments from each line

*This trick works perfectly in the shell !*

However `docker-compose up` says:

> ERROR: Invalid interpolation format for "command" option in service "foo": "printf ' something ...

If I escape the `$` as `$$` it says:

> ERROR: for foo  No closing quotation

How can I get this to work?

Comment: better to place in shell script and copy at dockerfield,

Comment: Try to escape the `$` sign with another `$`. You will get rid of the `invalid interpolation` error.

Comment: @b0gusb Thanks that was a good idea, but now it says `ERROR: for foo  No closing quotation`

Comment: Also, an issue probably comes from the quote in `# don't …`

Comment: @ErikMD No that is handled by the `cut` that strips inline comments

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here's a better way. The [`command`](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#command) docs don't show it, but I think it's standard YAML, so it's allowed.

```
foo:                               # valid comment
  image: foo:latest                # valid comment
  command:
    - something                    # explanation for this command
    - --arg                        # explanation for this switch
    - --a                          # explanation
    - --b hello
    - -c                           # this does...
    - --d spam                     # don't use this when...
    #some notes
    - --e ham                      # hmmm
    - --eggs                       # explanation
  restart: always                  # valid comment
```

Comment: For some reason this does not work for me :(

Comment: @mvc I suggest you open a separate question with a minimal reproducible sample.